# Unable to get spring dependency injection to work on a simple web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, web-config, spring.net

After much effort I have been unable to create a simple example of DI between my application and business layers.

Here is the spring snippet from my web.config:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebContextHandler, Spring.Web"/>
      <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core"/>
      <section name="parsers" type="Spring.Context.Support.NamespaceParsersSectionHandler, Spring.Core"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<spring>
    <parsers>
        <parser type="Spring.Data.Config.DatabaseNamespaceParser, Spring.Data"/>
        <parser type="Spring.Transaction.Config.TxNamespaceParser, Spring.Data"/>
    </parsers>
    <context>
        <resource uri="config://spring/objects"/>
        <resource uri="~/BusinessLayer/Business.xml"/>
        <resource uri="~/Web.xml"/>
    </context>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"     xmlns:db="http://www.springframework.net/database"     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.net/tx">
    <!-- Pages -->
    </objects>
</spring>
```

This is the Business.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.net http://www.springframework.net/xsd/spring-objects.xsd">
  <object id="UserBLL" type="Kupla.BusinessLayer.UserBLL, Kupla.BusinessLayer">
  </object>
</objects>
```

This is the Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.net http://www.springframework.net/xsd/spring-objects.xsd">

  <object type="default.aspx">
    <property name="UserBLL" ref="UserBLL"></property>
  </object>

</objects>
```

This is the definition of UserBLL.cs in the Business Layer:

```
namespace Kupla.BusinessLayer
{
    class UserBLL : IUserBLL
    {
        public int TestGetUserId()
        {
            int userId = 1;
            return userId;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the code in the application layer trying to access the business layer from default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using Kupla.BusinessLayer;

namespace Kupla
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private IUserBLL _userBLL;
        public IUserBLL UserBLL
        {
            set { _userBLL = value; }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int userID = _userBLL.TestGetUserId();
        }
    }
}
```

When launching the site, _userBLL is null. My DI is failing somewhere.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered `httpHandler`? From [Spring documentation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web.html#web-configuration):

```xml
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory, Spring.Web"/>
  </httpHandlers>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
  </httpModules>
  ...
</system.web>
```